# How can I remove lines from a file in Unix where the first two columns have the same value?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with several columns. I want to remove entire rows from this file at which the first and the second columns show the same value.

For instance, my file is as the following:

```
Variant         rsid         chr     pos
1:10177_A_AC    rs367896724     1    10177
1:10352_T_TA    rs201106462     1    10352
1:10511_G_A     rs534229142     1    10511
1:10616_CCGCCGTTGCAAAGGCGCGCCG_C        1:10616_CCGCCGTTGCAAAGGCGCGCCG_C        1       10616
```

I want to remove the line in which the value at `Variant` column is equal to `rsid` column, so I would like to obtain a final file such as the following:

```
Variant         rsid         chr     pos
1:10177_A_AC    rs367896724     1    10177
1:10352_T_TA    rs201106462     1    10352
1:10511_G_A     rs534229142     1    10511
```

I've tried to run the following commands:

```
awk '$1==$2{sed -i} input.file > output.file

awk -F, '$1==$2' input.file > output.file
```

But none of them worked.

How could I solve it by using `awk` and/or `sed`?

Comment: `awk '$1==$2{sed -i}` is like trying to ride your bicycle while driving your car. They're 2 completely different tools.

Comment: Are columns actually space separated (as in the source here)? Or are they TAB-separated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You already have [the best, general answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658055/22222), but in your specific case, you can also simply select all lines where the second field starts with `rs`:

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /^rs/' file
Variant         rsid         chr     pos
1:10177_A_AC    rs367896724     1    10177
1:10352_T_TA    rs201106462     1    10352
1:10511_G_A     rs534229142     1    10511
```

Answer (score 20):

You almost make it

```
awk '$1!=$2' input.file > output.file
```

This will keep line where first and second field are different (thus removing when equal).

- `-F,` is wrong because `,` is not your field separator and setting it that way will make awk misinterpret the line content
- `'$1==$2{sed -i}` is neither a awk, nor a sed function

Answer (score 4):

There may come a day (and this day may never come) when you need to do something "clever" in your file manipulation where the Awk solution becomes exceedingly complicated.  Rather than write out a script for a one-shot task, you want something that builds on your Awk experience. You want a [Perl One-liner](https://www.perl.com/article/perl-one-liners-part-1/).

Here's the equivalent of the above command (the `-a` flag says *do it like awk*)

```perl
perl -anE 'print if $F[0] ne $F[1]' input.file > output.file
```

or

```perl
perl -anE 'print if $F[1] =~ /^rs/' input.file > output.file
```

If you want to do that file change in place,

```perl
perl -i.bak -anE 'print if $F[0] ne $F[1]' input.file
```

will make changes to `input.file` and leave a backup in `input.file.bak`

If you'd like to execute some code after you finish the file, try the "kissing" operator `}{`

```perl
perl -i.bak -anE 'if ($F[0] ne $F[1]) {print} else {$del++} }{ $del ||= 0; say "Deleted $del lines"' input.file
```

The author of [Perl One-liners explained](https://catonmat.net/perl-one-liners-explained-part-one) has also written explainers on [Awk](https://catonmat.net/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one) and [Sed](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one) which you might find useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `awk` and `perl`, you can use plain bash:

```bsh
cat input.file | while read line; do a=($line); if [ "${a[0]}" != "${a[1]}" ]; then echo "$line"; fi; done
```

Line by line:

```bsh
cat input.file | while read line # read input.file line by line
do
   a=($line)                     # array assignment
   if [ "${a[0]}" != "${a[1]}" ] # compare the columns
      echo "$line"               # use quotes to preserve original spacing
   fi
done
```

If you're not interested in preserving the lines exactly in terms of spacing, this also works and is, in my opinion, more mnemonic:

```bsh
cat input.file | while read variant rsid char pos # read columns into variables
do 
   if [ "$variant" != "$rsid" ]  # compare the columns by name
   then
      echo "$variant     $rsid   $char   $pos" # replaced spaces with single tab
   fi
done
```

More about array assignments: https://riptutorial.com/bash/example/1550/array-assignments

Bash uses IFS (Internal Field Separator) to split columns when using read and for the array assignment. See: https://linuxhint.com/use-ifs-in-bash/

Comment: Use `while IFS=$'\t' read -ra a; do` to split the line into fields, instead of relying on an unquoted parameter expansion to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
m=open('filename','r')
import re
h=re.compile(r'\s+')
for b in m:
    fg=re.sub(h," ",b)
    rt=fg.split(' ')
    if (rt[0] != rt[1]):
        print fg
```

output

```
Variant rsid chr pos 
1:10177_A_AC rs367896724 1 10177 
1:10352_T_TA rs201106462 1 10352 
1:10511_G_A rs534229142 1 10511
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

```
raku -ne '.put unless .words[0] eq .words[1];'
```

OUTPUT:

```
Variant         rsid         chr     pos
1:10177_A_AC    rs367896724     1    10177
1:10352_T_TA    rs201106462     1    10352
1:10511_G_A     rs534229142     1    10511
```

For readability the keyword combination `unless/eq` was used. You could just as easily use `if/ne` (`ne` mnemonic: *not equal* ). The code above uses the `eq` string-equality operator. If you want to test numeric-equality, use `==` (remember to skip any non-numeric header line).

Note: You'll find many languages (Raku included) will balk at odd (introduced) lines, such as blank lines. For a solution that works even with internal/trailing blank lines (and removes them), use the following:

```
raku -ne 'if .chars {.put unless .words[0] eq .words[1]};'
```

*[ Language insight: "Hey, what's with all the leading periods?"  Raku make extensive use of a 'topic' variable `$_`, so you can alway track--and not have to repeatly denote--the name of the data structure you're manipulating (e.g. a 'topic' line from a text file). However even this `$_` can be abbreviated, thus `$_.words[0]` (meaning 'the first whitespace-separated element of the topic line') can be shortened further to `.words[0]`  ].*

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators
https://raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
grep -Ev '^(\S+)\s+\1\s' input.file >output.file
```

`\1` - back reference to pattern `(\S+)`.  the contents of both templates must match.
`-v` inversion flag - do not display lines matching the pattern.